# Apple changed their Memory Management Rule for Naming Convention

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, clang-static-analyzer

As stated in [Cocoa Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-SW4) from before

> You take ownership of an object if you create it using a method whose name begins with “alloc” or “new” or contains “copy” (for example, alloc, newObject, or mutableCopy), or if you send it a retain message.

haven't read it after December 2010, but since has changed since then to

> You “create” an object using a method whose name begins with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy” (for example, alloc, newObject, or mutableCopy).

Notice that now, it is required to have "copy" as a prefix. This resulted to a few memory related warnings from Clang Static Analyzer :(. After searching the interwebs, I haven't got to a conclusion as to why was this changed since this is one of the base foundations of Memory Management for iOS.

Does anybody know why? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There were some methods that contained "Copy" in their text, but were clearly not copying methods. For example, `+[NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:length:]`. It was, of course, possible to use annotations for the static analyzer to inform about the nonstandard behavior, but in general I suspect that almost nobody (yourself excepted) ever wrote a copy method that didn't start with `copy` or `mutableCopy`, so they decided to just simplify things.

I'm glad they did, frankly, as I've run into the opposite problem, where a method contained the word "Copy" but was not intended to return an owning reference.

Comment: +1 Definitely this. This wasn't a change in the rules, just a clarification in their documentation.

Comment: I guess they couldn't call it `+[NSData dataWithBytesInPlace:length:]`?

Comment: @MikeDeSimone They could have, but had no reason to at the time, and it's been in the API for many years now.